# Record command execution time

Tags: shell, history, command-line-interface

There is a cute way of loggin the start date/time of all commands in linux console. You should set the variable HISTTIMEFORMAT to "%F %T ". Then by running 'history' command you will see something like:

```
  512  2011-09-02 22:57:41 export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
  513  2011-09-02 22:57:42 ls
  514  2011-09-02 22:57:43 hist
  515  2011-09-02 22:57:45 history
```

This is very cool and useful. But my dream is to add to this log also the command execution time. I know that I can run 'time ./some_long_lasting_script' but I don't want to write time every time manually. Maybe there is some way of auto saving every command execution time?

Comment: Which shell do you use? bash? zsh? And what exactly do you want in your log file - there are myriads of `time` output formats like `xxx 0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 0,001 total` or something like:

`real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s`

What exactly do you want (which timings) and in what format?

Comment: I'm using bash. The ideal time is rounded seconds.

Comment: There are at least 3 possible timings - usually "user time", "system time" and "wall (total) time". Which one would you want?

Comment: Any time will suit me. I need this to record time of long lasting commands, and I don't need super accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't too distracting, you could change your prompt to display the current date and time.

If you're using bash, consider something like:

```
export PS1="[\D{%Y-%m-%d} \T][\u@\h \W]\$ "
```

which would look like:

```
[2011-09-03 03:39:21][james@fractal ~]$ echo $PS1
[\D{%Y-%m-%d} \T][\u@\h \W]$
[2011-09-03 03:39:30][james@fractal ~]$ vi
[2011-09-03 03:39:39][james@fractal ~]$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.93.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from qw-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.93.147): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=51.3 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.343/51.343/51.343/0.000 ms
[2011-09-03 03:39:44][james@fractal ~]$
```

You could, of course, tailor your prompt to your personal preferences.

To permanently change your prompt you can add that `export PS1=...` to your `~/.bashrc`file.  Alternatively, you could write aliases to toggle back and forth, for example, in your `~/.bashrc` file,

```
alias prompt_ts_on='export $PS1=...'
alias prompt_ts_off='export $PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "'
```

Note that `...` should be your choice of double-quote enclosed prompt string.

Some references on PS1 escape sequences: [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: The problem with this solutin that time in prompt shows the time when the promt was created instead of command run time.